# Getting a error in PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

My previous question was using the mysql_* which is depreciated. I am now learning to convert mysql_* to PDO but am getting an error when I try to run the file. The error is :

```
 <br /> <b>Catchable fatal error</b>: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted   to string in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\username_check.php</b> on line <b>13</b><br />
```

now my php is this:

```
<?php
require_once 'db_connect.php';

 $conn = dbConnect();
  if (isset($_POST['username'])) 
{
    $username = $conn->prepare($_POST['username']);

    if (!empty($username)) 
{
        $username_query = $conn->query("SELECT COUNT(id)
                                       FROM users
                                       WHERE username = '$username'");

 //where am getting the error line 13 is above//                               

                    $username_query->execute();
        $num_rows = $username_query->fetchColumn();

         if($num_rows==0)
         {
           echo "Username doesn't exist";
           exit;
         }
        else
        {
          echo "Username already exists";
          exit;
        }
   }
}

?>
```

my connection php is this:

```
 <?php

 function dbConnect(){
 $db = null;
 $db_host = "localhost";
 $db_username ="user";
 $db_pass ="pass";
 $db_name = "logins";

try{
$db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$db_host.';dbname'.$db_name,$db_username,$db_pass);

}
catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo '<p>Cannot connect to database !!</p>';
  exit;
}
return $db;
}
?>
```

I am also going to show my jQuery just incase the bug is in there:

```
 jQuery( '#box1' ).keyup(function(){
var username = jQuery(this).val();

jQuery( '#msg_out1' ).html('<img src="/click/ajax-loader.gif" width="43" height="11" /> &nbsp; Checking availability... ');

 if (username != '') {
 jQuery.post('/click/username_check.php', { username: username }, function(data){
    jQuery( '#msg_out1').text(data);

 });
 }else {
 jQuery( '#msg_out1' ).html('Choose a Username.').css('color','grey').css('font-size','15px').css('margin-left','40px');
 }
 });
```

Comment: One does not simply do `$conn->prepare($_POST['username']);`

Comment: the error message I searched for showed questions on here that did not relate to my problem, i used google. And I will do that thanks for the positive feedback

Comment: Please follow [this link](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers). to learn the how to use PDO.  And please don't remove this question. It will make you laugh to death after 5 months.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you're doing this the wrong way, preparing does not work like `mysqli_real_escape_string`..
What you need to prepare is the statement which in your case should look like this

`"SELECT COUNT(id)
                                       FROM users
                                       WHERE username = :username"`

then, when executing, you need to bind the parameters to your previous prepared statement so it should look like this

```
$username_query->execute(array(":username" => $_POST['username']));
```

So your final code which should work will look like this

```
<?php
require_once 'db_connect.php';

$conn = dbConnect();
if (!empty($_POST['username'])) 
{
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(id)
                                   FROM users
                                   WHERE username = :username");

    $stmt->execute(array(":username" => $_POST['username']);
    $num_rows = $stmt->fetchColumn();

     if($num_rows==0)
     {
       echo "Username doesn't exist";
       exit;
     }
    else
    {
      echo "Username already exists";
      exit;
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Thank for the explanation, the only reason I used prepare where I did was inplace of the mysql_escape_string. Also am getting an error of unexpected ";" on the end of line13. I removed the ";" and still got a error. I am reading the PDO manual now and still not seeing nothing

Comment: I added a ")" at the end of $stmt->execute(array(":username" => $_POST['username']);. And the code worked

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I am in for this rewriting craze, just to show the right way

db_connect.php

```
<?php
$db_host = "localhost";
$db_username ="user";
$db_pass ="pass";
$db_name = "logins";

$db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$db_host.';dbname'.$db_name,$db_username,$db_pass);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

main file

```
<?php
require_once 'db_connect.php';

if (isset($_POST['username'])) 
{
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE username = ?");
    $stmt->execute(array($_POST['username']));

    if($stmt->fetchColumn())
    {
        echo "Username already exists";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Username doesn't exist";
    }
}
```

Always try to avoid useless and unnecessary code.

All the explanationd for the above code you can find in the tag wiki: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info

Comment: thank you for answering and I will learn how to write better cleaner code, I am not learning from a school am learning from home using thenewboston.org tutorials so please bare with me

Comment: Another thing, when I run this code it says syntax error unexpected { on line 11

Comment: Then you need to learn PHP syntax first.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah... that's super wrong.

```
$username_query = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users WHERE username = ?";

if( ! $sth = $conn->prepare($username_query) ) {
  // probably an error in your SQL syntax
  die( "Prepare error: " . var_export($conn->errorInfo(), true) );
}

if( ! $sth->execute(array($_POST['username'] ) {
  // probably a SQL integrity constraint violation [ie: duplicate key] or a server error
  die( "Execution error: " . var_export($sth->errorInfo(), true) );
}

if( $sth->rowCount() ) {
  echo "Username exists.";
} else {
  echo "Username does not exist.";
}
```

Comment: This is no better, you know

Comment: @YourCommonSense what is wrong with it, exactly?

Comment: `die( "Execution error:`. Site user will have no idea what are you showing to him

Comment: This *is* a productive information I provided. It's only your attitude and prejudice that makes you unable to make any product out of it.

Comment: BTW, your condition to see if any records found is wrong. Just noticed it

Answer (score 0):

Read the PHP Manual carefully before you use it. There is a lot of examples on it and explain how to use it in Detail.

In Manual it said:

- *PDO::query() executes an SQL statement in a single function call, returning the **result set** (if any) returned by the statement as a PDOStatement object.*

so if you use `query()` to fetch your result, you don't need to run `prepare()` and `execute()`, just do it as follows:

```
$sql = 'select count(id) from test';
$return = $dbh->query ( $sql );
$result = $return->fetchColumn();
```

If you will execute the query multiple times in the code below, you can use a **prepare statement**(something like a compiled code):

- *Prepares an SQL statement to be executed by the PDOStatement::execute() method.*

and to do it:

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users WHERE username = ?";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(1,$username);
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->fetchColumn();
```

Don't misunderstood these two kinds of statements.

Comment: Thank you for the answer I am reading the manual now to better understand these

Comment: @user3052886 Good. don't hurry coding, make it clear what it is first.